# How to close a showdialog completely?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dispose, showdialog

I've created a process where I can't really use the Show / Hide function of forms.  That's why I am using a Showdialog at the moment.

The code I am using to create the next form (and close/dispose the next one) is:

```
Private Sub btnControle_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnControle.Click
    Try
        Dim frmlocatie As New frmLocatie
        Me.Close()
        Me.Dispose(True)
        frmlocatie.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

In my application, I have to be able to reach one of the 7 forms from anywhere.
Some extra info about the applicaiton:
We have to choose a location, choose sublocation, choose room, and then choose the item.  And from within every of those forms, we can click on 'location' for example and choose another one.

[image]

My main problem at the moment is, that after about 20 forms open+close, the system gives an error on a random form (while building it) and is saying: 
StackoverflowException was unhandled: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackoverflowException' occured.
[image]

I think that this is because of a memory issue of the scanner, and that it didn't closed the forms correctly. (even with close + dispose)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Based on the comments I used the Call Stack, see Image below.
[image]

I also tried the other comment and catched the error:

```
?ex.ToString
"System.StackOverflowException: StackOverflowException
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.WL.SetPos()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._SetBoundsCore()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Size()
bij OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.BatteryLife..ctor()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.InitializeComponent()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie..ctor()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.lblLocatie_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.lblLocatie_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.lblLocatie_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.lblLocatie_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.lblLocatie_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.lblLocatie_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.lblLocatie_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.lblLocatie_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.lblLocatie_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLocatie.lblLocatie_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmMain.btnControle_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
bij BradyPDT.frmLogin.btnNext_Click()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
bij System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
bij Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
bij BradyPDT.frmSplash.Main()
"
```

Comment: Do you create new forms in catch blocks if they fail to create by chance? (pseudo for comment readability): try{Dim oForm as new frmVerdieping()} catch{oForm = new frmVerdieping()}

Comment: Yes I do,  Is that a problem?
Edit: some have a try catch, other don't, depending on the other code from within the sub.

Comment: It can be a number of things that would cause this issue. It's possible you are not releasing objects after you are done with them in your classes, unrelated to opening and closing your forms. IMHO you need to debug and watch the stack trace etc...

Comment: It will cause a stack overflow if a form fails to initialize properly. Put a breakpoint in each catch block that Dims a new form and wait for it to hit, and then look at the exception to find out what's going on.

Comment: It probably has nothing to directly to do with that dialog.  As mentioned, the call stack should reveal whats wrong

Comment: I tried the call stack and the try catch block (I edited my question, so you can see the result). Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you have code in a one or more constructors or FormLoad to click a button,  `frmLocatie.btnVorige` is causing `frmMain` to load which somehow causes the `btnControle` click event.  Normal form initialization and loading does not result in click events

Comment: I was combining two buttons with the same sub to exit the window.
I have splitted them up, but still no luck.
I have edited my question again, with the latest call stack and error log.